# javax.persistence annotations missing optional elements?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, playframework, ebean

We're in the process of upgrading our Play framework application from 2.3.10 to 2.4.8, and with that, upgrading from Ebean 3.x to 4.6.2.

I'm now seeing compilation errors, stating that some `javax.persistence` annotations are missing fields. Both versions of Ebean depend upon version 1.0 of `javax.persistence`.

The strange thing is that IntelliJ is showing the annotations as missing the optional elements, but the Javadoc for the annotation mentions the optional element. Note that compilation also fails in

For example, here is the source that IntelliJ shows for `javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint`:

```
/**
 * This annotation is used to specify that a unique constraint 
 * is to be included in the generated DDL for a primary or secondary table.
 *
 * <pre>
 *    Example:
 *    &#064;Entity
 *    &#064;Table(
 *        name="EMPLOYEE", 
 *        uniqueConstraints=
 *            &#064;UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"EMP_ID", "EMP_NAME"})
 *    )
 *    public class Employee { ... }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @since Java Persistence 1.0
 */
@Target({TYPE}) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)

public @interface UniqueConstraint {

    /** (Required) An array of the column names that make up the constraint. */
    String[] columnNames();
}
```

Comment: what "optional" elements? You display JPA 1.0. You need JPA 2.0 or JPA 2.1. So pick up the later JPA API jar integrate it into your build and you see all annotation attributes for later versions of JPA

Comment: See also JPA javadocs which says very clearly "name" is added in JPA 2.0 https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html#name--

Comment: Ah, I see. This is strange; something must have been importing JPA 2.x previously. That solves it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using JPA 1.0 (in your build process somewhere, and what IDEA shows you). The "name" attribute of the [UniqueConstraint annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html#name--) was introduced in JPA 2.0. You need to change the build of IDEA to use JPA 2.0.